# AsPylib: ctypes and ndpointer

Tags: python, ctypes

I am having difficulties getting a code to work as per [the AsPylib documentation website](https://www.aspylib.com/doc/aspylib_geometry.html). The documentation says that I should be able to translate an image by 40.3 pixels in the vertical direction, 150.2 pixels in the horizontal direction through the following command:

```
data2 = astro.translate_Bspline(data, [40.3, 150.2], 3)
```

Although all the other geometrical transformations mentioned on the documentation page work well for me, it throws the following error:

```
Error in aspylib.astro.translate_Bspline()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Aspylib_v3.0.0\aspylib\astro\transform.py", line 40, in translate_Bspline
    cdll.Bspline.Translate.argtypes = [c_long, c_long, c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32)]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hfedd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 446, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hfedd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'Bspline' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hfedd\Downloads\new8.py", line 19, in <module>
    data2 = astro.translate_Bspline(data, [40.3, 150.2], 3)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Aspylib_v3.0.0\aspylib\astro\transform.py", line 54, in translate_Bspline
    raise Exception("more than 3 consecutive failures, execution stopped")
Exception: more than 3 consecutive failures, execution stopped
```

I understand that something is incorrect in the below transform.py file and not done according to the [numpy documentation on C-Types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html).
Can someone help, please.

```
# -*- coding: iso_8859_1 -*-

import numpy as np
import platform as pf
import aspylib.conf as conf

from ctypes import c_long, c_float, cdll
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer 

def translate_Bspline(images, shift, spline_degree):
    """
    ---------------------
    Purpose
    Translates an image (or list of images) by non-integer shifts in both X and Y directions.
    B-Spline interpolation with arbitrary order (from 2 to 9) is used to calculate the translated pixels.
    ---------------------
    Inputs
    * images (2D or 3D Numpy array) = array that contains the data of one image (2D case) or the data of a list of images (3D case).
    * shift ([float, float]) = 2 elements list that contains respectively the shifts in X (vertical) and Y (horizontal) directions.
    * spline_degree (integer) = the degree of the B-Spline that is used for interpolation : it can be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.
    ---------------------
    Output (2D or 3D Numpy array) = transformed image data.
    ---------------------
    """

    ierror = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if len(images.shape)==2:
                dim = 1
                dim_x, dim_y = images.shape
            else:
                dim, dim_x, dim_y = images.shape
                
            indata = np.ascontiguousarray(np.array(images, dtype = np.float32))
            dxy = np.ascontiguousarray(np.array(shift, dtype = np.float32))
            outdata = np.ascontiguousarray(np.empty(images.shape, dtype = np.float32))
            
            if pf.system()=='Windows':
                cdll.Bspline.Translate.argtypes = [c_long, c_long, c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32)]
                cdll.Bspline.Translate(dim,dim_x,dim_y,indata,dxy,spline_degree,outdata)
            elif pf.system()=='Linux':
                mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("libbspline.so")
                mydll.Translate.argtypes = [c_long, c_long, c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32)]
                mydll.Translate(dim,dim_x,dim_y,indata,dxy,spline_degree,outdata)

            del indata
            del dxy
            break
        except:
            print("error in aspylib.astro.translate_Bspline()")
            ierror+=1
            if ierror>3:
                raise Exception("more than 3 consecutive failures, execution stopped")
            pass

    return outdata
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot of material, I found that since Python version 3.8 one needs to explicitly state the path to DLL. It worked to add two lines of code:

```
import os

os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Aspylib_v3.0.0\aspylib\lib\DLLs win 64bits")
```

as stated below.

```
# -*- coding: iso_8859_1 -*-

import numpy as np
import platform as pf
import aspylib.conf as conf

from ctypes import c_long, c_float, cdll
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import os

def translate_Bspline(images, shift, spline_degree):
    """
    ---------------------
    Purpose
    Translates an image (or list of images) by non-integer shifts in both X and Y directions.
    B-Spline interpolation with arbitrary order (from 2 to 9) is used to calculate the translated pixels.
    ---------------------
    Inputs
    * images (2D or 3D Numpy array) = array that contains the data of one image (2D case) or the data of a list of images (3D case).
    * shift ([float, float]) = 2 elements list that contains respectively the shifts in X (vertical) and Y (horizontal) directions.
    * spline_degree (integer) = the degree of the B-Spline that is used for interpolation : it can be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.
    ---------------------
    Output (2D or 3D Numpy array) = transformed image data.
    ---------------------
    """

    ierror = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if len(images.shape)==2:
                dim = 1
                dim_x, dim_y = images.shape
            else:
                dim, dim_x, dim_y = images.shape
                
            indata = np.ascontiguousarray(np.array(images, dtype = np.float32))
            dxy = np.ascontiguousarray(np.array(shift, dtype = np.float32))
            outdata = np.ascontiguousarray(np.empty(images.shape, dtype = np.float32))
            
            if pf.system()=='Windows':
                os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Aspylib_v3.0.0\aspylib\lib\DLLs win 64bits")
                cdll.Bspline.Translate.argtypes = [c_long, c_long, c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32)]
                cdll.Bspline.Translate(dim,dim_x,dim_y,indata,dxy,spline_degree,outdata)
            elif pf.system()=='Linux':
                mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("libbspline.so")
                mydll.Translate.argtypes = [c_long, c_long, c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), c_long, ndpointer(dtype=np.float32)]
                mydll.Translate(dim,dim_x,dim_y,indata,dxy,spline_degree,outdata)

            del indata
            del dxy
            break
        except:
            print("error in aspylib.astro.translate_Bspline()")
            ierror+=1
            if ierror>3:
                raise Exception("more than 3 consecutive failures, execution stopped")
            pass

    return outdata
```